How to fix this? "This txn hash was found in our secondary node and should be picked up by our indexer in a short while."
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x664156fcb7fec578f32edcd9e95b62d920a8642e7cd63f6552ac917b44baee45
Guys, this transaction has been like this for 6 hours. It says "should be picked up by our indexer in a short while", but this "short while" is taking too long.
The transfer was made from Revolut to the wallet in the transaction.
Does anyone know how to solve it? please help, USDT is stuck.

Well the transaction seems to have completed successfully, already some time ago.
Remember that Etherscan is just an arbitrary service - it's not a source of truth about the state of the blockchain. It may be even down, or just have some distruption in its services, but that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the blockchain itself.
So probably there was just some hiccup in Etherscan at the time. In any case, everything is fine now.
